# how to create system environmental variables on remote servers

Tags: c#, .net, network-programming

We have a number of web servers and app servers set up that all connect to some databases on our network.  We're trying to make our code more secure by moving the database connection strings out of the code.  I have set up some system environmental variables that hold the connection strings and can read them within the app so that works fine.  However, thinking through making this a production solution for security means I need a way to register all these variables on all of our servers and that could be a bit of a maintenance nightmare down the road.

So I am wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to set up a central distribution app that could register all the variables across a list of servers whenever they need updated?  I'm working in a windows .net environment.  Or is there a better solution to store this information outside of the code base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting MS SQL Server, I'd recommend using Windows Authentication and Integrated Security so you just need to provided host and database names in your connection.

The remaining connection string is usually best put into your respective Web.config/App.config. If you insist on distributing environment variables, use the Windows Registry - you can access it easily via Remote PowerShell or .NET.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll look into the registry powershell option.  We are targeting ms sql server for most of the databases but also mysql for one of them.  We don't want to store the connection string in the app or web config files since those would be part of the solution checked into git.

Comment: @geoffswartz you can keep them in git, just dont check in webconfigs that have real credentials in them.  Keep a webconfig in there with all your keys and fake values, then use web config transforms.

Comment: @maccettura Was just about to recommend [Web/App config transforms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx) as well.

Comment: Thank you both for that.  I'll look into the transforms too!